# The splitting fields of two irreducible polynomials over $Z / p Z$ both of degree 2 are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

$p$ is a prime. Let $ f_1, f_2 \in Z / p Z [t]$ both of degree 2 and irreducible. Show that they have isomorphic splitting fields.

---

My approach was let $ K_1 = F(\alpha_1, \beta_1) / F$ be the splitting field of $f_1$, and let $K_2 = F( \alpha_2, \beta_2) / F$ be the splitting field of $ f_2$. Then I have trouble finding any relations between $ \alpha$'s and $\beta$'s. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: It is possible to find a polynomial $f$ (of degree $p^2$) such that both fields you are considering are minimal splitting fields of $f$.

Comment: Try finding an automorphism of $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}[t]$ mapping $f_1$ to $f_2$: What do automorphisms of $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}[t]$ look like?

P.S. Note that $F(\alpha_i,\beta_i)=F(\alpha_i)=F(\beta_i)$ for both $i\in\{1,2\}$.

Comment: @Servaes I think I have something. So I only need to show that $ F(\alpha_1)$ is isomorphic to $F(\alpha_2)$. Since both fields are finite, do I always get an isomorphism by sending $ \alpha_1 $ to $\alpha_2$?

Comment: You get an isomorphism *if and only if* $f_1=f_2$. But I prefer DonAntonio's approach to my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas (hopefully you've already studied this stuff's details):

For a prime $\;p\;$ and for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$, prove that the *set* of all the roots of the polynomial $\;f(x):=x^{p^n}-x\in\Bbb F_p[x]\;$ in (the, some) algebraic closure $\;\overline{\Bbb F_p}\;$ of $\;\Bbb F_p:=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ , with the usual operations modulo $\;p\;$ , is a **field** with $\;p^n\;$ elements, which we denote by $\;\Bbb F_{p^n}\;$

From the above it is immediate that $\;\Bbb F_{p^n}\;$ is the minimal field which contains *all* the roots of $\;f(x)\;$ and is thus this polynomial's splitting field over $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ .

Now, apply the above to the particular case $\;n=2\;$ and deduce at once your claim.

Comment: Thanks. I guess to continue I just apply the argument to the $n =2$ case and find a field with $p^2$ elements which is the splitting field of $ x^{p^2} -x $. But why is this field a splitting field for both $ f_1$ and $f_2$?

Comment: Because (1) either **all** the three fields (the splitting field I proposed and the two polynomials') are one and the same field (the only one with $\;p^2\;$ elements) , or (2) because **all** three fields are two-dimensional spaces over the same base field $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ ...

Comment: Ok, so that's because finite fields with same number of elements are isomorphic? But if so why can't we directly say both the splitting fields of $f_1$ and $f_2$ have $p^2$ elements thus are isomorphic?

Comment: Yes, and also yes: we can say that. My argument above is designed just to help you say easily why it is so, since if you already knew this then what's this question's point?